# Sorting a vector of coordinates c++

Tags: c++, vector, std

I have a graph in which given one node, I have to generate an ordered vector of all the others nodes of the graph ordered by the closest distance.

So, I have a vector with all the coordinates and a separated coordinate to compare it with all the others. My idea is to create a map that will save for any coordiante (node), a vector with all the other coordiantes ordered by closest position.

Can I do this using std::sort? Or any way to simplify this?

Thanks

Comment: That is not a useful question. Of course you can sort a vector using the std::sort as long as you fill the vector somehow, you can use std::copy and a function object (which calculate the distance) and then sort it.

Comment: The issue I'm having is I don't know how to use the std::sort to compare all the vector with just a given element. I don't even know if this is possible or if I have to find another solution. I just need some guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I do this using std::sort?

I think you are going in wrong direction . If you keep a vector with coordinates of all nodes and sort them an basis of distance from current node , it will not necessarily compare 2 coordinates in the given vector ! .
This is required by `std::sort`.
To overcome this , you need to precompute distances of all nodes from given node and then define your `compare()` function for `std::sort()` , which compares on the basis of smallest distance .
Total time complexity : `O(N logN)`.

> Or any way to simplify this?

Instead there is an easier way .
Given your node , Do a [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) using a queue . When performing BFS , you 1st visit ALL nodes at a distance `1` from original node , then at a distance `2` and so on .... This is exactly what is required .
Total time complexity : `O(N)`.

Hope this helps !

Comment: The problem with the BFS is I lost the relation between the nodes. I just have coordinates, there is no path between them.

Comment: Then you just need to create a graph with all nodes connected to each other . Takes `O(N)` space .

Comment: let me know if you have any doubt .

Comment: sorry this does not take O(N) space , but takes O(N^2) space . A better way will be to use `min-heap` . If you want , i will explain it .

Comment: I'm still trying. The problem with this is that all the nodes are connected between them. How Am I going to do a BFS like this?

Comment: start BFS from the given node and `mark nodes visited` and don't visit them again . So , it will run on each node exactly once

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have your node as global you can do something like this

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

std::pair<float,float> MyNode(10,20);

struct CalculateDistance{
    float operator()(std::pair<float,float> temp) {
        //Use MyNode to calculate the distance between MyNode and temp and return it
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<std::pair<float,float> > listOfCoordinates;

    listOfCoordinates.push_back(std::make_pair(10.20,30.2));
    listOfCoordinates.push_back(std::make_pair(9.20,31.2));
    listOfCoordinates.push_back(std::make_pair(12.20,39.2));
    listOfCoordinates.push_back(std::make_pair(15.20,-30.2));

    std::vector<float> distances;

    std::copy(listOfCoordinates.begin(),listOfCoordinates.end(),distances.begin(),CalculateDistance());
    std::sort(distances.begin(),distances.end());
}
```

But this is just a way, you should post some code or be more specific so someone can help you. I didn't do the actual calculation, the `CalculateDistance()` should return a float representing the distance. I didn't compile my code, just to show you the main idea.

If you want to keep the relationship between the nodes and the distances you can do something like:

```
typedef std::pair<float,float> Coordinate;
typedef float Distance;
typedef std::pair<Coordinate,Distance> Node;
```

and use a vector of Node